# compare two .aspx files before uploading

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I was wondering whether there is away to compare two .aspx pages. I have a website on my local machine and the same website on a production server. What i will like to do is compare .aspx page from my local and production server to see what the differences are.

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you accessing and uploading to the remote server?

Answer (score 2):

[Windiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) (free) and [beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (commercial) will compare files and whole directories.

Most diff software will let you compare any two files and report on differences. There are many free and commercial tools out there.

They also work with [UNC paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Answer (score 2):

I use diffmerge by source gear, its free and very effective.

Here is the link: http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/

Answer (score 1):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) has native support for FTP, SFTP, and FTPS, in addition to UNC paths.  You can just load your local directory one one side and an FTP URL on the other, and it will compare your entire site and let you copy files or make edits.

Answer (score 0):

[Winmerge](http://winmerge.org/) will compare the files.  You can also use this tool to merge the code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Anish (tho I think a typo crept in) - for windows diff it has to be 'Winmerge'. Its free, open source and imo the best so far. You can get it here: http://winmerge.org

It integrates nicely with Visual Studio as an 'external Tool', instructions here: http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/